# Open source rocket development

Tags: united-states, european-union, open-source-software, research, itar

Is it possible to collaborate openly (publicly) world-wide with others to develop a suborbital/orbital capable rocket/launcher and to publish the resulting know-how (both software and hardware)? There are laws that restricts exports of arms ([ITAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Traffic_in_Arms_Regulations) in US, similar in EU) which may apply to publishing such info.

It looks like ITAR does not care about information that is [publicly available](https://www.unr.edu/sponsored-projects/compliance/export-controls/publicly-available) (ITAR [paragraph 120.11](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/120.11)) but I am not sure if I understand it correctly. Can someone confirm?

These questions may be related:

- [ITAR tag on Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itar)
- [Trade restrictions on open source software](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41212/trade-restrictions-on-open-source-software)
- [Do international sanctions have an impact on Open Source Software?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/32981/do-international-sanctions-have-an-impact-on-open-source-software)
- [Why can't I ask my question about amateur space projects and development?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/why-cant-i-ask-my-question-about-amateur-space-projects-and-development)

Comment: This is one question applied to multiple jurisdictions. I see no lack of focus of the sort which should lead to closure, and I oppose closing this for such a reason.

Answer (score 3):

### It’s perfectly legal for private individuals and organisations to develop rockets

Just like it’s legal for them to develop aircraft or motor vehicles. Space X, Boeing and BMW are all private organisations.

While any of these could be used as weapon delivery systems, they aren’t weapons.

There are a bunch of laws and regulations that they must comply with, but that’s true of any business.

Comment: I am asking about open source development which may differ from private closed source development where you only publish (or sell) the final product. It looks like ITAR does not care about information that is [already public](https://www.unr.edu/sponsored-projects/compliance/export-controls/publicly-available) - according to [paragraph 120.11](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/120.11). So can you confirm once again publishing know-how that covers functional rocket parts (which may together form a whole orbital rocket) is allowed?

Comment: I’m sure software is involved in rockets but why are you focused on that to the exclusion of hardware ?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I am not excluding hardware. By "open source" I mean both software and hardware. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: In both common law and civil law jurisdictions the default position is that you can do anything unless the law says you can’t. There is no law that says you can’t. There are laws about how you can launch rockets and how to make them safely (the same laws about how to make crackers safely, in general) but none that prohibit this.

Comment: I also do not see why open source implementation would make any difference as opposed to a proprietary development.

Comment: "There are a bunch of laws and regulations that they must comply with" doesn't really answer how ITAR and other export control laws apply to such development.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite With open source development you deal with export of information (depends on the "level" of openness but lets assume public worldwide access) and that is the main concern. There have been requests to restrict online access to US persons only ([DEFCAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFCAD)).

Comment: Thanks - Also proprietary development with a cross national team could have sone similar concerns.